# Quick processing of large file

Tags: multithreading, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails project for Ecommerce app which has background job for data processing as well. Recently we received an XML file from a customer with around 300+ orders(around 35000+ lines in file). This file is taking around 9 hours to process, though the customer is expecting this to process in 2-3 hours.

The most obvious solution that came to mind is using threading to concurrently process 10-15 orders to reduce processing time. I implemented the same using Java executors framework and created a pool of say 3 threads. The Grails project uses hibernate as ORM.

The process followed is as below :

```
1.) Address details are verified and If not present created in DB.
2.) Item details are verified and if not present created in DB.
3.) Order against the saved item is created/updated.
```

Now, for testing purpose, 3 orders are submitted to 3 threads in pool. The first thread which reaches ITem creation(Step 2) locks the item object and other two threads keep waiting at that point. Once the first thread completes all of its operations, the other two threads fail with below exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not insert: [com.test.ABCITem]; SQL [insert into party_item_relations (version, active_flag, amazonasin, b2b_downloaded, baseuom, bom, card_size, case_size, colour, configured, cost, country_of_origin, currency, date_created, drop_ship, end_date, external_id, flex_field1, flex_field10, flex_field2, flex_field3, flex_field4, flex_field5, flex_field6, flex_field7, flex_field8, flex_field9, gender, gtin_code, height, heightuom, image_file, ingredients, internal_item, item_category, item_description, kanban_enabled, key_terms, last_updated, lead_time, length, lengthuom, long_description, manufacturer, model, moq, number_of_cards, over_ship_percent, pack_size, parent_item_category, parentitem_id, party1_id, party1item_number, party2_id, party2item_number, planner_code, price, product_family, product_group, product_type_name, sales_channel, scent, size, source_rank, start_date, status, tam_split, upc_code, variation_theme, weight, weightuom, width, widthuom) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert: [com.test.ABCITem]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:639)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:911)
    at com.test.ABCITem.save(ABCITem.groovy)
    at com.test.ABCITem$save$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.MasterDataService.createPartyItemRelation(MasterDataService.groovy:259)
    at grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper.run(PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper.groovy:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert: [com.test.ABCITem]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.performSaveOrReplicate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:991)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1064)
```

I have looked at various solutions for this error but mostly suggest ordering of where clause fields. Other solutions like increasing timeout of innodb engine have not worked.

My project structure looks like below.(This is pseudo code and not exact classes)

1.) Runnable implementation to execute each order as a new thread.

```
public class BackGroundTask implements Runnable{
    private List<JSONObject> requests;

    public BackGroundTask(final List<JSONObject> requests){
        this.requests = Lists.newArrayList(requests);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.dataUtilsService.processData(this.requests);

    }
}
```

2.) Third party service which receives XML file and start new thread from executor pool for each order.

```
public class ThirdPartyService{

def executorService

    public void process(File file){
        Document doc = xmlParser.parse(file);
        NodeList orders = ordersData.getElementsByTagName(TAG_ORDER)
        for (Element order : orders) {
            //order converted to List<jsonobject> and passed below.
            executorService.submit(new backGroundTask(requests));
        }
    }
}
```

3.) Processor service structure which actually processes the data.

```
public class DataUtilsService{

    @Transactional(propagation=PropagationType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void processData(List<JSONObject> requests){
        //Loops through requests and processes data.
        item.save();
    }
}
```

Please suggest what else other than threads can be used here for concurrent processing so as to reduce processing time.

Comment: It sounds like an awful long processing time for such a small amount of data. Almost 2 minutes per order? Can you tell us why it takes so long? You should definitely know the answer to this question. What I mean is that multi-threading is not the first solution that comes to my mind, and I think you might be overlooking more obvious solutions, like optimizing the database, the queries, etc.

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where it's spending its time?

Comment: For each order, there are a lot of support tasks that are done. When an order is processed, lot of combination are used to find the correct item if existing or new item is added. Then inventories are updated, shipments are auto created for this customer. Reservations and some custom data associated with customer is also updated. The code might not be an optimised one but as per the task list, it might be taking approximately the correct time

Comment: Also the domain relationship is as Orders -> (hasmany) OrderLines. All of the above processing happens for each line. I checked the processing time for one order with 200 lines. Each line got processed per second and in around 150 seconds so 200 records(1 order and its 200 orderLines) got processed. So the current processing speed is around 30 orders per hour. I need some way to bring that to 100 orders per hour :(

Comment: I agree with KIKO and David, you may want to remove the threading code and try a single threaded solution. Try profiling the code using grails-melody-plugin, http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/sergiomichels/grails-melody-plugin. This will help you identify where the code is spending the majority of it's time. In my experience I've found my largest bottleneck is calling object.save() too often in a loop without batching them can kill performance.   Example of batching calls to save, http://www.tothenew.com/blog/batch-processing-in-grails/